# How to handle native iOS Alerts in Appium using Java

Tags: java, ios, alert, appium

I try to write tests for an app, which shows iOS native alert for Location (This app would like to use your current location). I tried this code

```
driver.switchTo().alert.accept();
```

This actually works for other alerts, but not for native ones.

Also I noticed, that since 2nd time I run a test(even there is nothing but an sysout), it fails because of SessionNotCreatedException, but if I remove that alert from app, everything is ok.

I use Appium 1.3.4.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

Try adding to your Desired Capabilities `("autoAcceptAlerts",true)`.
It doesn't work perfectly but you should try it.

You can also try doing:

```
driver.findElement(By.name("OK")).click();
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: autoAcceptAlerts will accept all alerts on the applications. if the test require to not accept the alert, or using custom alert it will chose the default positive button.