# How to handle alert which pop-up during Automation?

Tags: java, ios, instruments, ios-ui-automation, appium-ios

`Details` : I am using `iOS-Driver` to automate the iOS apps . The debug apps are only allowed to be launched by **instruments** .

1. I start the xyz debug app .
2. Then i go to the app which is download from app store so obviously this is not debug app . I start testing it works .
3. When alert comes in this app i am not able to handle the alert . The automation script binds the alert handler only with the apps which we launch through instruments so alert handler is not detected by the other app which i am testing i.e app downloaded from app store .

How do i handle such alerts or dismiss alerts ?

Comment: Does this help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28126701/how-to-handle-native-ios-alerts-in-appium-using-java

Comment: @chedabob NO . I already tried .

Answer (score 0):

Find element by using class `UIAALert`, this will give you reference of the Alertview currently on the screen. Now use method `findElementsByClass` passing the `UIAALert` as input parameter. This will give you the buttons available inside alert view. You can tap on any of the button you want now.