# Appium: Handle native alerts using ChromeDriver on Android

Tags: android, cordova, appium

Cordova App, deployed to an Android emulator. My app shows a notification prompt, which I want to test using Appium.
We're using the notifications plugin, which is showing a native notification in this case. I first only want to Accept the prompt with an empty string.

I have tested, to find the OK button:

`var ok = browser.driver.findElement(by.name('Ok'));
ok.click();`

The error is that the Ok button cannot be found.

I've also tried:

`var alert = browser.switchTo().alert();
alert.accept();`

This results in an error that there is no alert open. The appium log in this case:

`info: JSONWP Proxy: Replacing sessionId 09700a539828795c9ea9d583b68b2250 with 483d2b53-eb0a-4ce2-a697-8776dadf6954
info: <-- GET /wd/hub/session/483d2b53-eb0a-4ce2-a697-8776dadf6954/alert_text 200 7.530 ms - 254
info: --> GET /wd/hub/session/483d2b53-eb0a-4ce2-a697-8776dadf6954/alert_text {}
info: JSONWP Proxy: Proxying [GET /wd/hub/session/483d2b53-eb0a-4ce2-a697-8776dadf6954/alert_text] to [GET http://127.0.0.1:9515/wd/hub/session/09700a539828795c9ea9d583b68b2250/alert_text] with body: {}
info: JSONWP Proxy: Got response with status 200: {"sessionId":"09700a539828795c9ea9d583b68b2250","status":27,"value":{"message":"no alert open\n  (Session info: webview=39.0.0.0)\n  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.20.353145 (343b531d31eeb933ec778dbc...`

There are related posts, but none of the solutions work, e.g:
[How to handle native iOS Alerts in Appium using Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28126701/how-to-handle-native-ios-alerts-in-appium-using-java)
[how to handle alerts in android using appium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24635354/how-to-handle-alerts-in-android-using-appium)

Anyone who can help me shed a light on this?

Comment: Can you please share the snapshot of your inspector?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know what you mean? The Appium log? Or something else?

Comment: Probably what @Gaurav means is a snip of Appium Inspector OR UIAutomatorViewer for the view you are trying to access.

Comment: [This will answer how to handle the native alert dialog box in Android](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41029436/6731329)

Answer (score 0):

I encountered exactly this problem and finally came up with a solution.

Assuming you're using [wd-bridge](https://github.com/sebv/wd-bridge), first expose the `wdBrowser` object as a global in your tests via your protractor config:

```
onPrepare: function () {
    var wd = require('wd'),
        protractor = require('protractor'),
        wdBridge = require('wd-bridge')(protractor, wd);
    wdBridge.initFromProtractor(exports.config);
    global.wdBrowser = wdBrowser;
},
```

Then assuming the Cordova alert you're dealing with is generated by [cordova-plugin-dialogs](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-dialogs) by `navigator.notification.alert()`, you can do the following:

```
function acceptAlert() {
    let webViewContext;

    return wdBrowser
        .currentContext()
        .then((currentContext) => {
            webViewContext = currentContext;
        })
        .context("NATIVE_APP")
        .then(() => {
             return wdBrowser.elementById("android:id/button1").then((el) => {
                  return el.click();
              }, (err) => {
                  console.error("Alert dialog not found");
                  return wdBrowser;
             });
        })
        .then(() => {
            return wdBrowser.context(webViewContext);
        });
};
```

This function:

- stores a reference to the Webview context containing your Cordova app
- switches to the native context
- finds the native alert OK button by its native ID
- clicks it
- restores the original Webview context

So you can use it like this:

```
acceptAlert().then(() => {
    console.log("Alert accepted");
});
```